# What should be the Best directory structure/architecture for angularjs in your project

Tags: angularjs

i am developing a new massive project in `larvel5` and `angularjs` , i just needed suggestions for what should be the best directory structure for angularjs to organize your code in inside my projects.how should be `modules`, `controllers`, `directive` and `factory` etc managed inside my project. my default directory structure is like

```
app
  controllers
  services
 directives
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In this, There are two web projects, one is or web api and another one is for client web page (SPA).

You just need a empty web project to start an angular project.

Index.html - It is the main html page for your application. All other pages (partial pages) for your project can be placed Inside the directory Pages.

Scripts - All your js files can be placed inside this directory. You can differentiate all your js files into it's sub-directories.

Answer (score 1):

An ideal AngularJS app structure should be modularized into very specific functions. We also want to take advantage of the wonderful AngularJS directives to further compartmentalize our apps. Take a look at a sample directory structure below:

[image]

index.html

The index.html lives at the root of front-end structure. The index.html file will primarily handle loading in all the libraries and Angular elements.

Assets Folder

The assets folder is also pretty standard. It will contain all the assets needed for your app that are not related your AngularJS code. There are many great ways to organize this directory but they are out of scope for this article. The example above is good enough for most apps.

App Folder

This is where the meat of your AngularJS app will live. We have two subfolders in here and a couple JavaScript files at the root of the folder. The app.module.js file will handle the setup of your app, load in AngularJS dependencies and so on. The app.route.js file will handle all the routes and the route configuration. After that we have two subfolders – components and shared. Let’s dive into those next.

Components Folder

The components folder will contain the actual sections for your Angular app. These will be the static views ,directives and services for that specific section of the site (think an admin users section, gallery creation section, etc). Each page should have it’s own subfolder with it’s own controller, services, and HTML files.

Each component here will resemble a mini-MVC application by having a view, controller and potentially services file(s). If the component has multiple related views, it may be a good idea to further separate these files into ‘views’, ‘controllers’, ‘services’ subfolders.

This can be seen as the simpler folder structure shown earlier in this article, just broken down into sections. So you could essentially think of this as multiple mini Angular applications inside of your giant Angular application.

Shared Folder

The shared folder will contain the individual features that your app will have. These features will ideally be directives that you will want to reuse on multiple pages.

Features such as article posts, user comments, sliders, and others should be crafted as AngularJS Directives. Each component here should have it’s own subfolder that contains the directive JavaScript file and the template HTML file.

In some instances, a directive may have it’s own services JavaScript file, and in the case that it does it should also go into this subfolder.

This allows us to have definitive components for our site so that a slider will be a slider across the site. You would probably want to build it so that you could pass in options to extend it.

You can read detailed article from [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure)

You can also take a look at these links  :
[Angularjs style guideline](https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide) and 
[another article](http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-app-structuring-guidelines/)

Answer (score 0):

found a solution for my `angularjs` directory structure.
[image]